# Using a GPU card with more Streaming Mulitprocessors

Tags: cuda, gpu

Presently i am using a GeForce GPU card with 2 SM's . I am running some experiments on that GPU card and observing that the code is performing 5 times faster when compared to a similar CPU implementation. I was curious that if I run exactly the same code in a more powerful GPU card such as the Tesla GPU, will I achieve better execution times when compared to the time obtained while using the GeForce card. If yes, why is this the case? If not, how should I modify my code (at a high level) as I expect a stronger GPU card to give me more speedup.

Answer (score 2):

Each SM can run at most 8 or so blocks at a time (often fewer, for blocks that require more resources such as shared memory), so GPUs with a larger number of SMs can run a correspondingly-larger number of blocks.

To future-proof your code to larger GPUs, specify a number of blocks in your kernel invocation that is based on (and greater than) the number of SMs in the system.  This is queryable by looking at `deviceProp::multiProcessorCount` or calling `cuDeviceGetAttribute` with `CU_DEVICE_ATTRIBUTE_MULTIPROCESSOR_COUNT`.

Answer (score 2):

Better performance should be expected from a GPU with more SMs if all of the following conditions hold:

- the new GPU has the same or newer architecture relative to your existing one,
- the new GPU has the same or better clock speed,
- the new GPU has the same or better memory throughput, and
- (by far most importantly), the code uses enough thread blocks to keep more than 2 SMs busy.

Note that the current hardware trend is to increase the number of cores, so maximizing the number of threads is typically very important.  For example, the Kepler architecture triples the core count relative to the Fermi architecture.